# How to avoid non-symmetric padding and simply shrink the box a little?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some text

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>This is a text with class jumbotron.</h1>
</div>
```

And I can't find a way to remove the extra space to the right of the text (where the red arrow is).

Edit:

I would like to have the text drawn as if the width demand of 200px requires, but then have a box placed around such that the padding is correct as well, if neccessary making the box slightly smaller than required.

Result with code below:

[image]

Goal: box edge approximately where the red line is:

[image]

---

Edit:

`text-align justify` leads to the right padding, but I would like to keep the text as it is above:

[image]

---

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.jumbotron h1 {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 3px solid #ffffff;
      width: 200px
    }
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>This is a text with class jumbotron.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you set a fixed width on the element the element will be that width. Are you actually asking about `justified text`? --> http://jsfiddle.net/t5em4b96/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing:border-box;`

```
.jumbotron h1 {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 3px solid #ffffff;
      width: 200px;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Wouldn't be better with max-width?

Comment: @MatejŽvan replacing width with max-width does not seem to change the result.